# IN clause of RecordId field in UserRecordAccess object is not working

Tags: apex

I am facing an issue while using IN clause of RecordId field in UserRecordAccess object.
If I hard code the value, then it works fine.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

Following works:

```
List<UserRecordAccess> userRecordAccesses = [select RecordId, HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where RecordId IN ('001Z000000cNgoA') and UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

But this doesnt:

```
Set<Id> searchedAccIds = new Set<Id>();
searchedAccIds.add('001Z000000cNgoA');
List<UserRecordAccess> userRecordAccesses = [Select RecordId,HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where RecordId IN:searchedAccIds and UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

**Edit**: For those who may find it helpful, below is information from Debug log for both code statements:

```
15:34:56.058 (58706000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|select RecordId, HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where (RecordId IN ('001Z000000cNgoA') and UserId = :tmpVar1)
15:34:56.070 (70513000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:1



Execute Anonymous: Set<Id> searchedAccIds = new Set<Id>();
Execute Anonymous: searchedAccIds.add('001Z000000cNgoA');
Execute Anonymous: List<UserRecordAccess> userRecordAccesses = [Select RecordId,HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where RecordId IN:searchedAccIds and UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
15:41:18.056 (56081000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
15:41:18.056 (56094000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
15:41:18.056 (56659000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[1]|<init>(Integer)
15:41:18.056 (56698000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[1]|<init>(Integer)
15:41:18.057 (57355000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[3]|Aggregations:0|select RecordId, HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where (RecordId = :tmpVar1 and UserId = :tmpVar2)
15:41:18.064 (64521000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:0
```

Comment: This works fine in my dev org using accounts.  This code should work.  Is there any other factors that you arent mentioning that could cause this

Comment: I would throw some System.debugs in your code, specifically after you build your set to see what your set contains, and then check the debug logs to see if your SOQL query does in fact return something.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja,@James-loghry - As mentioned by JimRae,it works if I use a list instead of set, which is bewildering indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work correctly if you use a List instead of a Set.

```
List<Id> searchedAccIds = new List<Id>();
searchedAccIds.add('001Z000000cNgoA');
List<UserRecordAccess> userRecordAccesses = [Select RecordId,HasReadAccess from UserRecordAccess where RecordId IN:searchedAccIds and UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

This bug is now listed as a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4wwAAC

Comment: It should work with a set as well, it shouldn't be necessary to use a list

Comment: Just an FYI, I was merely commenting, I did not give you the down vote.  While i think it is unnecessary to use the list, I don't think answer is worthy of a down vote.

Comment: I experienced the same symptom in my dev org as Mahesh reported, and when I switched to a list, it did work correctly.

Comment: Thats odd, I am using the same code (with accounts) and it works fine using a set

Comment: I have used the same code using set  with Account it works fine but this phenomena happens only  with  UserRecordAccess object

Comment: @JimRae, Thanks. As u mentioned, it works if I use a list instead of set. I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer, but i have accepted it.

Comment: I've hit this myself and opened a case, #10801090. I'm pushing to get a known issue listed so that anybody without premium support to can track its resolution.